# Скриншот по таймеру и сохранение в файл. С++

Tags: c++, screenshots

Я уже кучу всего перерыл в поисках адекватного ответа. Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет по таймеру делать скриншот экрана и сохранять его в файл, добавляя счетчиком +1 к названию. Например сохранять в директорию C:\Windows и назвать их Screenshot1,Screnshoot2 и т.п. Может у кого завалялось в курсачах или лабах на плюсах такое или может быть кто напишет если будет не сложно.

Вот код который я более менее смог найти, но я не могу заставить его работать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <time.h>

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid) {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    UINT  num = 0;
    UINT  size = 0;

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if(size == 0)
        return -1;

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if(pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);
    for(UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if( wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0 )
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }    
    }
    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return 0;
}

void gdiscreen() {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    IStream* istream;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
        HDC scrdc, memdc;
        HBITMAP membit;
        scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
        int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
        membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
//      bitmap.Save(L"screen.jpeg", &clsid, NULL); // To save the jpeg to a file
        bitmap.Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);

        // Create a bitmap from the stream and save it to make sure the stream has the image
//      Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(istream, NULL);
//      bmp.Save(L"t1est.jpeg", &clsid, NULL);             
        // END

        delete &clsid;
        DeleteObject(memdc);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(0,scrdc);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}

int main()
{
        clock_t t1 = clock();
    int i;
    int iterations = 10;
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++){
        gdiscreen();
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    printf("%d iterations: %0.0f fps\n", iterations, iterations/((double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я смог сам разобраться и нашел способ через WinAPI, а дальше еще и дописал что бы можно было больше скринов. Единственное что не отказался если бы помогли дописать так,что бы скриншоты сохранялись в определенную директорию. Если кому помог, то не поскупитесь на плюсик, а то сам спрашивал это и заминусовали ни за что. Ну и если вы хотите помочь еще больше, то допишите так, что бы создавались скриншоты в определенной директории))

```
void screenshot(int i) {
HWND hwnd;
hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
RECT client_rect = { 0 };
GetClientRect(hwnd, &client_rect);
int width = client_rect.right - client_rect.left;
int height = client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top;
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);
TCHAR M[50];
wsprintf(M, TEXT("Screenshot%d.bmp"), i);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

BITMAPINFO bmp_info = { 0 };
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmp_info.bmiHeader);
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

int bmp_padding = (width * 3) % 4;
if (bmp_padding != 0) bmp_padding = 4 - bmp_padding;

BYTE *bmp_pixels = new BYTE[(width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height];;
GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, height, bmp_pixels, &bmp_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHeader;
HANDLE bmp_file_handle = CreateFile(M, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

// Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
DWORD dwSizeofDIB = (width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

//Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

//Size of the file
bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

//bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM

DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)&bmp_info.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)bmp_pixels, (width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

//Close the handle for the file that was created
CloseHandle(bmp_file_handle);

DeleteDC(hdc);
DeleteObject(hbmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
delete[] bmp_pixels;
```

}

Comment: `wsprintf(M, L"C:\\dir\\Screenshot%d.bmp", i);` обязательно ставить по два слеша, потому что двойной слеш конвертируется в одинарный. Если путь получен с аргументов файла настроек и т п то удваивать слеши не нужно, т.к. убирает удвоение компилятор.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое))